# Bootstrap does not apply css style when changing the viewport size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is really a newbie question, but somehow I can not figure it out why the example below does not work. The idea is that bootstrap applies different css rules depending on the view port size. But somehow Bootstrap always applies the latest css rule in the style comment. No matter if the viewport size is xs, sm, md or lg.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--  To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming,
        add the viewport meta tag to your <head>.  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap grid system</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    .col-xs-12 {
      background-color: #204d74;
      font-size: 40px;
    }
    .col-sm-6 {
      background-color: #449d44;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
      background-color: #ac2925;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
      background-color: #ffff00;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4. .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4 col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4. .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4 col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4. .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4 col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap *is* applying different rules depending on viewport size. The problem is your custom code *isn't*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember here that those classes are always applied to each of the divs (resizing doesn't add or remove classes) meaning that the most recent one will be used regardless of viewport size. Instead you need to use media queries to define the CSS at different widths. Assuming you have default Bootstrap sizes, this should work:

```css
body {
  background-color: #204d74;
  font-size: 40px;
}
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color:#449d44;
    font-size:30px;
  }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color:#ac2925;
    font-size:20px;
  }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-color:#ffff00;
    font-size:10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4. .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4 col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4. .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4 col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4. .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4 col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```